# How does a queue interact with a foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach

I was really suprised that this question doesn't really have an answer.
For example I have a foreach loop iterating through the queue(I am using the .Net versions) what exactly happens to the queue in the foreach?
Does it simply iterates like a standard enumerator? Or does it use the `Dequeue()` functionality.

For clarity:

```
Queue<int> q = new Queue<int>();
foreach(int i in q)
{
    // what happens in this loop?
}
```

Comment: [The documentation for Queue.GetEnumerator()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.getenumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states "Enumerators can be used to read the data in the collection, but they cannot be used to modify the underlying collection." (This applies to most classes, but not all! It definitely applies to Queue though.)

Comment: Simply by looking at [MSDN reference of Queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.110).aspx) you will see that it implements IEnumerable, hence it can be used in `foreach` (which uses enumerators)

Comment: @MatthewWatson your comment sounds like an answer to me

Comment: @MatthewWatson But why does it use the Enumerator like an array? Why not a separate implementation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Does it simply iterates like a standard enumerator? Or does it use
>   the Dequeue()

Instead of iterating the queue, it looks up elements by index and bucket in its internal array, using the `Queue<T>.GetElement` method. You can see this in the [implementation of the `Enumerator` class returned by `Queue<T>.GetEnumerator()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/queue.cs,6e60ad9827d7127e):

```
public bool MoveNext() 
{
    if (_version != _q._version)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(
                                    ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);

    if (_index == -2)
        return false;

    _index++;

    if (_index == _q._size) 
    {
        _index = -2;
        _currentElement = default(T);
        return false;
    }

    _currentElement = _q.GetElement(_index);
    return true;
}
```

Where [`GetElement`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/queue.cs,29c22142ec052f71) is simply:

```
internal T GetElement(int i)
{
    return _array[(_head + i) % _array.Length];
}
```

Comment: Why does it use the standard Array implementation when it is a Queue?

Comment: Because that is how a `Queue` is implemented internally. When you think about it, a `Queue` is simply an abstract data-type which exposes a FIFO implementation. An array is sufficient to achieve that implementation, all you need to know if what you head and tail is

Comment: This explains quite a lot more than the MSDN Docs, Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

As per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.getenumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Enumerators can be used to read the data in the collection, but they cannot be used to modify the underlying collection.

Therefore it's safe to assume that using a `foreach` on a queue will not dequeue any items.